# MongoDB ShardingKey error: Document does not contain shard key for pattern

Tags: mongodb, nosql, sharding

I'm trying to set up sharding for mongoDB.
The Shard is created successfully but everytime I try to populate the collection with help of a json file, I get the following error: Document does not contain shard key for pattern
[image: Document error]

Im declaring the shard using the following command:

```
sh.shardCollection("velo.Users",{Zipcode:1})
```

[image: Sharding]

```
mongoimport --host localhost --port 1000 --db velo --collection Users "path"
```

This is the json file im trying to populate my collection with:

```
{
"Users": [
{
    "Email": "Lars.Bouman@gmail.com",
    "Number": "156 ",
    "UserId": 1,
    "Zipcode": "2060",
    "Street": "Somméstraat",
    "City": "Antwerpen",
    "CountryCode": "BE",
    "Name": "Bouman Lars"
},
{
    "Email": "Julia.van.der.Zee@telenet.be",
    "Number": "43 ",
    "UserId": 2,
    "Zipcode": "2610",
    "Street": "Europalaan",
    "City": "Wilrijk (Antwerpen)",
    "CountryCode": "BE",
    "Name": "van der Zee Julia"
}       
]
}
```

I've already tried using "Users.Zipcode" but I get the same error.

Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Expanding on the answer from @David, your shard key cannot be an array element inside of a document (multi-key index).  This is because more than likely you will have two different values in the array in one document, and sharding is about data distribution based on this key.  If you have two values in one document, which shard should the document live in?  If multi-key indexes were allowed the system could not determine which shard to target.  So, following answer by David, by creating individual documents the system can now target a single shard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you want your sharded collection to contain one user per document, your json (put into a file named Users.json in this example) should be

```
[
{
    "Email": "Lars.Bouman@gmail.com",
    "Number": "156 ",
    "UserId": 1,
    "Zipcode": "2060",
    "Street": "Somméstraat",
    "City": "Antwerpen",
    "CountryCode": "BE",
    "Name": "Bouman Lars"
},
{
    "Email": "Julia.van.der.Zee@telenet.be",
    "Number": "43 ",
    "UserId": 2,
    "Zipcode": "2610",
    "Street": "Europalaan",
    "City": "Wilrijk (Antwerpen)",
    "CountryCode": "BE",
    "Name": "van der Zee Julia"
}       
]
```

and then assuming that your json is in a file named "Users.json" your mongoimport command would be as follows:

```
mongoimport --host localhost --port 1000 --db velo --collection Users --file=Users.json --jsonArray
```